# I am trying to connect mongodb with spring boot. I am confused when to use which maven dependency amongst the following:

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, maven, spring-data

I am trying to connect mongodb with spring boot. I want to configure using AbstractMongoClientConfiguration, MongoConfigurationSupport abstract classes and MongoClient class and use MongoTemplate, MongoRepository and MongoClient. I am confused when to use which maven dependency amongst the following:

1. org.mongodb mongodb-driver-sync
2. org.mongodb mongo-java-driver
3. org.springframework.data spring-data-mongodb
4. org.springframework.boot spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb

Can someone please help?

Comment: Try to read this article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-tutorial

Comment: @4EACH baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-tutorial along with baeldung.com/java-mongodb helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, according to Baeldung tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-tutorial

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```